# Event Subscriber In Microsoft Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, events, vba

Is there any way to have an event subscriber to the immediate window (using Debug.Print, for instance) in VBA under Microsoft Access for debugging?

Comment: Nope.  The Immediate Window is basically a console and it doesn't even contain a control for displaying text - it's drawn directly onto the client area. You would need to be able to hook the IO directly from the debugger. VBA\6 programmers have been trying this for decades with no success...

Comment: Subscribe to what events?   Look into the `WithEvents` keyword used on variable declaration e.g. `Dim WithEvents foo as Access.Form`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is a one-stop for all of Microsoft Access emitting objects ...

```
Option Explicit
'* In a class module

Private WithEvents o_PageEvents As Access.Page
Private WithEvents o__ControlInReportEvents As Access.[_ControlInReportEvents]
Private WithEvents o_LabelEvents As Access.Label
Private WithEvents o_RectangleEvents As Access.Rectangle
Private WithEvents o_LineEvents As Access.Line
Private WithEvents o_ImageEvents As Access.Image
Private WithEvents o_CommandButtonEvents As Access.CommandButton
Private WithEvents o_OptionButtonEvents As Access.OptionButton
Private WithEvents o_OptionButtonInOptionEvents As Access.[_OptionButtonInOption]
Private WithEvents o_CheckBoxEvents As Access.CheckBox
Private WithEvents o_CheckBoxInOptionEvents As Access.[_CheckBoxInOption]
Private WithEvents o_OptionGroupEvents As Access.OptionGroup
Private WithEvents o_BoundObjectFrameEvents As Access.BoundObjectFrame
Private WithEvents o_TextBoxEvents As Access.TextBox
Private WithEvents o_ListBoxEvents As Access.ListBox
Private WithEvents o_ComboBoxEvents As Access.ComboBox
Private WithEvents o_ObjectFrameEvents As Access.ObjectFrame
Private WithEvents o_PageBreakEvents As Access.PageBreak
Private WithEvents o_ToggleButtonEvents As Access.ToggleButton
Private WithEvents o_ToggleButtonInOptionEvents As Access.[_ToggleButtonInOption]
Private WithEvents o_PaletteButtonEvents As Access.PaletteButton
Private WithEvents o_SubFormEvents As Access.SubForm
Private WithEvents o_SubReportEvents As Access.SubReport
Private WithEvents o_CustomControlEvents As Access.CustomControl
Private WithEvents o_CustomControlInReportEvents As Access.[_CustomControlInReport]
Private WithEvents o_TabControlEvents As Access.TabControl
Private WithEvents o_SectionEvents As Access.Section
Private WithEvents o_SectionInReportEvents As Access.[_SectionInReport]
Private WithEvents o_PageHdrFtrInReportEvents As Access.[_PageHdrFtrInReport]
Private WithEvents o_FormEvents As Access.Form
Private WithEvents o_ReportEvents As Access.Report
Private WithEvents o_References_Events As Access.References
Private WithEvents oDispAttachmentEvents As Access.Attachment
Private WithEvents oDispEmptyCellEvents As Access.EmptyCell
Private WithEvents oDispWebBrowserControlEvents As Access.WebBrowserControl
Private WithEvents oDispNavigationButtonEvents As Access.NavigationButton
Private WithEvents oDispNavigationControlEvents As Access.NavigationControl
```

Some examples of their use are given in these links |[Adding Classes WithEvents to MS Access Form](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/4b0e610f-7d3e-42dc-a584-05eb4987b230/adding-classes-withevents-to-ms-access-form?forum=accessdev)|[MS Access WithEvents in Class Module for OnClick Event](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/01913ad3-d011-45e9-97cd-fb063fc6e0aa/ms-access-withevents-in-class-module-for-onclick-event?forum=accessdev)|.

Also a Stack Overflow similar question [Click event handler withevents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3424564/global-click-event-handler-withevents)

Comment: @S Meaden Thank you for your response. Excuse me if this is a trivial question, but I am still confused over how would I use the above code snippet to, say, print out all the events being fired from a certain object by passing its reference. Would you mind updating the answer with an example. I would really appreciate that.

Comment: I don't normally do Access and couldn't immediately get it working.  I have included some links showing examples.

Comment: Thank you so much!!