# VBA WithEvents not working

Tags: vba, events, controls, userform

I am basically creating a list of items that are generated at runtime. The items are listed on a userform as labels(the items are stored in a linked list). With each item, I want to add a spinbutton so I can move the items up and down the list. I the spinbuttons are created just fine, the events I have coded do not work?? I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Probably something simple...

This is the class module to hold the events: cls_Spin_Btn

```
Private WithEvents Spin_Events As SpinButton

Private Sub Spin_Events_SpinUp()

    Debug.Print "Hey. Spin button worked."

End Sub

Public Property Set SetNewSpinButtion(newSpinBtn As MSForms.SpinButton)

    Set Spin_Events = newSpinBtn

End Property
```

This is code is calling from a module:

```
Function AddRunToForm(f As UserForm, r As ProductionRun, top As Integer) As Integer

Dim Run_SpinBtn As MSForms.SpinButton
Dim spinBtn As cls_Spin_Btn

Set Run_SpinBtn = f.Controls.Add("Forms.SpinButton.1", r.ProdID & "_SBtn", True)
Set spinBtn = New cls_Spin_Btn

With Run_SpinBtn

    .top = ProdID_Lbl.top
    .Left = 5
    .height = 10
    .Width = 12
    .height = 18
    .Visible = True

End With

Set spinBtn.SetNewSpinButtion = Run_SpinBtn

AddRunToForm = ProdID_Lbl.top + ProdID_Lbl.height

End Function
```

This code is called from a loop in the same module creating labels and spinbuttons for each item. What am I doing wrong? Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: You need to keep each `spinBtn` in scope (eg) by adding it to a collection with global (module-level) scope. See Gary's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083603/vba-using-withevents-on-userforms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your userform code module, put this

```
Private mcolSpinButtons As Collection

Public Property Get SpinButtonCollection() As Collection

    If mcolSpinButtons Is Nothing Then Set mcolSpinButtons = New Collection

    Set SpinButtonCollection = mcolSpinButtons

End Property
```

That will give you access to a module level variable that will stay in scope as long as your userform is open.  When you put cls_Spin_Btn instances in that collection, they will also stay in scope.

Then in your function, once you create the new spin button class instance, add it to the collection

```
f.SpinButtonCollection.Add spinBtn, spinBtn.Name
```

Comment: Works like a charm! That was the simple thing I missed. Thank you very much.