# VBA: Detect changes in any textbox of the userform

Tags: vba, events, userform

There is a userform that has many textboxes and I need to detect changes in each. So I have write a subroutine for every textbox in the form and it turns out a large piece of code.
As the code for every textbox is the same I want to optimize it. So is it possible to write just one subroutine that detect changes in any textbox of the form?

Comment: Yes, with a class and WithEvent. See [VBA: Using WithEvents on UserForms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083603/vba-using-withevents-on-userforms)

Comment: See Control Arrays. From Help. A control array is a group of controls that share the same name and type. They also share the same event procedures. A control array has at least one element and can grow to as many elements as your system resources and memory permit; its size also depends on how much memory and Windows resources each control requires. The maximum index you can use in a control array is 32767. Elements of the same control array have their own property settings. Common uses for control arrays include menu controls and option button groupings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way do achieve that is to use a class along with `WithEvents`

Here's a minimal example:

Code for the class module named `mytextbox`:

```
Private WithEvents txtbox As MSForms.TextBox


Public Property Set TextBox(ByVal t As MSForms.TextBox)
    Set txtbox = t
End Property


Private Sub txtbox_Change()
    ' code for handling the event
End Sub
```

And the code inside the Userform, assuming you want to handle the events of every Textbox

```
Private myEventHandlers As Collection

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim txtbox As mytextbox

    Set myEventHandlers = New Collection

    Dim c As Control
    For Each c In Me.Controls
        If TypeName(c) = "TextBox" Then
            Set txtbox = New mytextbox

            Set txtbox.TextBox = c

            myEventHandlers.Add txtbox
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```