# Actions for multiple similar dynamically created command buttons

Tags: vba, excel, dynamic, commandbutton

I am writing a program in Excel VBA that will basically start with one textbox and one command button, and the command button will create a new textbox and command button underneath it, and that command button will in turn create a new textbox and command button, and so on.  Hope you followed that mess.

I can create the initial button no problem (it has to be dynamically created so it has the opportunity to be deleted later).  My problem is then with creating the `click()` event handler.  I need all the `click()` events to do the same thing, but name the new Objects relative to its own name.  This is all blowing my mind, I would really appreciate a little help.

Feel free to ask for specific information, but I haven't really been able to wrap my head around the topic well enough to write some test code yet.

Comment: This might help : [Using WithEvents on UserForms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083603/vba-using-withevents-on-userforms)

Comment: @z̫͋ I'm familiar with `WithEvents`, but I don't know how to use dynamically initialized (and named in a manner unforeseen) buttons' click events.  For instance, the name of a button may be `"NewButton" & i` and I don't know how to make event handlers for that, even with `WithEvents`.

Comment: With WithEvents it doesn't matter what the name of the button is. You create a variable that sinks the event and assign the button to the variable. The button's name doesn't have anything to do with it.  In my opinion, it's better to create all the controls you need and toggle the .Visible property rather than trying to create the controls at runtime. You still may want a common procedure even if you do it that way.

Comment: @DickKusleika Could you show me some code with generic names in <> tags instead of specifics, to help me understand? I see what you're saying about WithEvents, just not sure how I'd go about doing this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a custom class module called CEventClass (Insert - Class Module, F4 to change the name). Type this code into the class module

```
'These are declared WithEvents so the events are
'exposed to us
Public WithEvents cmdEvent As MSForms.CommandButton
Public WithEvents tbxEvent As MSForms.TextBox


'This will fire for any control
'assigned to cmdEvent
Private Sub cmdEvent_Click()

    MsgBox cmdEvent.Caption

End Sub

'This will fire for any control
'assigned to tbxEvent
Private Sub tbxEvent_Change()

    If Len(tbxEvent.Text) < 6 Then
        tbxEvent.BackColor = vbYellow
    Else
        tbxEvent.BackColor = vbWhite
    End If

End Sub
```

Now create a Userform with no controls on it.  Put this code in the form's code module

```
'These will keep the class instances in
'scope for as long as the form is loaded
Private mEventButtons As Collection
Private mEventTexts As Collection

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim cmd As MSForms.CommandButton
    Dim txt As MSForms.TextBox
    Dim clsEventClass As CEventClass

    Set mEventButtons = New Collection
    Set mEventTexts = New Collection

    'Create two commandbuttons
    Set cmd = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1", "FirstName")
    cmd.Top = 10
    cmd.Left = 10
    cmd.Caption = "First"
    'Create a new instance of CEventClass and
    'assign the button to cmdEvent
    Set clsEventClass = New CEventClass
    Set clsEventClass.cmdEvent = cmd
    mEventButtons.Add clsEventClass

    Set cmd = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1", "SecondName")
    cmd.Top = 50
    cmd.Left = 10
    cmd.Caption = "Second"
    Set clsEventClass = New CEventClass
    Set clsEventClass.cmdEvent = cmd
    mEventButtons.Add clsEventClass

    'Create two textboxes and assign them to new instances
    'of the class
    Set txt = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1", "ThirdName")
    txt.Top = 10
    txt.Left = 150
    Set clsEventClass = New CEventClass
    Set clsEventClass.tbxEvent = txt
    mEventTexts.Add clsEventClass

    Set txt = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1", "FourthName")
    txt.Top = 50
    txt.Left = 150
    Set clsEventClass = New CEventClass
    Set clsEventClass.tbxEvent = txt
    mEventTexts.Add clsEventClass

End Sub
```

Now when you run the form, those two events will fire if you click/change the control.

You may note that there is no AfterUpdate event for the textbox. That event is not actually a textbox event, but an event of the control container for the textbox, so you can't expose it this way. That's one reason I prefer to create all the controls at design time and hide or unhide them as needed. I still might use WithEvents for some controls just so I don't have to repeat code so much. But for things like TextBox_AfterUpdate, I just create all the event procedures at design time.

**Update:**

If you want the event to create new buttons, you have to do a couple more things. First, you have to expose the collection outside of the userform.  You add this to your Userform module

```
Public Property Get EventButtons() As Collection
    Set EventButtons = mEventButtons
End Property
```

Then you change your commandbutton event code to create a new button

```
Private Sub cmdEvent_Click()

    Dim cmd As MSForms.CommandButton
    Dim clsEventClass As CEventClass

    Set cmd = cmdEvent.Parent.Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1", cmdEvent.Caption & "1")
    cmd.Top = cmdEvent.Top + 40
    cmd.Left = cmdEvent.Left
    cmd.Caption = cmdEvent.Caption & "1"
    Set clsEventClass = New CEventClass
    Set clsEventClass.cmdEvent = cmd
    cmdEvent.Parent.EventButtons.Add clsEventClass

End Sub
```

This creates a new button 40 points below whichever was clicked. You don't say what your logic is for naming or positioning, so I assume you can work that out. Use cmdEvent.Parent to get a reference to the Userform.

Comment: This has the potential to do what I want, but I need clicking the button to create a new button on the userform, which will create another button when clicked, as many times as the user wants.

Comment: Okay, when I try to include a textbox in that creation process you put in the update, I got a Runtime Error 91.  Here's the culprit: `Set tbx = tbxEvent.Parent.Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1")`   Why won't this work?

Comment: Are you putting that in cmdEvent_Click()? Then it should read `Set tbx = cmdEvent.Parent.Controls...`