# Create a label with VBA and change its name : How can I click it?

Tags: excel, vba, label

I am trying to create labels in a Frame during runtime with VBA. The problem is, I want to be able to click them once they are created. So this is what I made : (my labels are attached to a Frame)

```
Set TheLabel = Frame.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", Visible = True)
    With TheLabel
        .Name = "Label" & i
        .Caption = gTab(i, 2) & "_ " & gTab(i, 0) & Temp
        .Left = 6 + gTab(i, 2) * 12
        .Top = 12 + 16 * i
        .Height = 12
        .Width = 200
    End With
```

Where i is an integer (it's the number of the current label).
With this code, I imagine the name of my Label is now Label1, Label2 etc.

But even with this piece of code:

```
Private Sub Label1_Click()
    Frame.Height = 200
End Sub
```

It doesn't seem to work.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: How are you creating the `Private Sub Label1_Click()` code? Are you also creating that using VBA at runtime?

Comment: Nope I am creating it before runtime. I don't know how to create code during runtime

Answer (score 0):

To add controls to a userform at runtime, with code behind the controls, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8986622/4243498) and [this one as well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1923457/4243498).