# Assign code to _Change method of a Combobox

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

below code adds a `ComboBox` in cell `A3` of a worksheet. It also writes code so that when the value is changed in the `ComboBox`, cell `A2` is updated with the value. Here is the code:

```
Sub AddComboBox()

    Dim oWS As Worksheet: Set oWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet7")
    Dim oRN As Range: Set oRN = oWS.Range("A3")
    Dim oCB As Object
    Dim sCode As String
    Dim iLR As Integer

    ' Get last row for column D (holds the values for combobox)
    With oWS
        iLR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    ' Create Combobox
    With oRN

        Set oCB = oWS.OLEObjects.Add("Forms.Combobox.1", Left:=.Left, Top:=.Top, Height:=.Height, Width:=.Width)
        oCB.ListFillRange = "Sheet7!D1:D" & iLR
        oCB.Name = "cmbTest1"
        oCB.Object.Font.Size = 8

    End With

    ' Set code to add for the Combobox
    sCode = "Private Sub " & oCB.Name & "_Change()" & Chr(13) & _
            "   ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(" & Chr(34) & oWS.Name & Chr(34) & ").Range(" & Chr(34) & "A2" _
                & Chr(34) & ").Value = Me." & oCB.Name & ".Value" & _
            "End Sub"

    ' Add the code for Combobox
    With ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(oWS.Name).CodeModule
        .InsertLines .CountOfLines + 1, sCode
    End With

End Sub
```

Code works fine but for it to work, user has to make sure that `Trust access to the VBA project object model` is selected in **Trust Center**. My question is, is there another way to approach this problem so that user doesn't have to change the settings on their PC? i.e. maybe just assign a macro in a Class module. I did give [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10224511/assign-code-to-a-button-created-dynamically) a try but I need to be able to pass the name of the `ComboBox` to the called UDF but have no idea how to do that or if that is even possible with this approach? Reason why I want to pass the name of `ComboBox` is because: the naming convention for `ComboBox` will give me the cell address where the `ComboBox` is created. I need this as each row in the sheet will have multiple `ComboBoxes` (created dynamically) and there will be multiple rows in the sheet

Comment: The issue here is trying to dynamically insert new VBA.  Instead of creating a new event for each control you can re-use a shared event.  See this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083603/vba-using-withevents-on-userforms/1923457#1923457) for a well-presented solution.

Comment: @destination-data that's exactly what I wanted to do. I will give it a go. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Trust Centre is there for a reason.

In order to get around it, you may put the xl-vba file in a specific folder. Then add this folder as a trusted location, through the Trusted Settings like this:
Trust Center>Trust Center Setting>Trusted Locations

But I am not sure whether this would be less job than making sure that the Trust access is selected. However, it is an option.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Vityata. Unfortunately this approach wont work for me as the user wont have access to the same folders as me. I completely agree and understand the reasoning behind the trust center hence the question if there is another approach I can use.

Comment: @Zac, tag me if you find an answer.