# Show value in Textbox1 from Worksheet depending on ComboBox1 selection

Tags: vba, excel

Wondering if you could help with adding a value from my Worksheet to my TextBox1 depending on what ComboBox1 item is selected.

So far I have this for my ComboBox1 to pull a list from my Worksheet

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
' *** Load the companies into the delivering firm combo box ***
For Each cell In Range("RejectTitle")
    If cell <> "" Then
        Me.RejectTitleNm.AddItem cell
    End If
Next cell
End Sub
```

Now I am trying to have my UserForm show a value from Worksheet into TextBox1 depending on ComboBox but I believe I'm heading down the wrong path?

```
Private Sub RejectTitleNm_Change()
    Me.TextBox1.Text = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E5").Value
End Sub
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083603/vba-using-withevents-on-userforms maybe that'll help

Comment: @GibralterTop - how is your link related to the OP's question?

Comment: You can use `Find()` or `Vlookup` to locate the selected value on the worksheet, then take the value from the required column on the same row.

Comment: @TimWilliams the question is "I'm heading down the wrong path?". Just posting the link in case it'll help, as I said. Maybe the event is never firing? Who knows. Maybe there's syntax errors in the event register code. I don't think anyone can know what this question is asking and be certain.

Comment: There is some confusion.  OP, please define what RejectTitleNm is.

Comment: Sorry guys, RejectTitleNm is the name of ComboBox1

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
Private Sub RejectTitleNm_Change()

    Dim f As Range, v

    v = Me.RejectTitleNm.Value
    'find the selected value in the source range
    Set f = Range("RejectTitle").Find(v, lookat:=xlWhole)

    Me.TextBox1.Text = ""
    If Not f Is Nothing Then
        'got a match: get value from ColB on same row
        Me.TextBox1.Text = f.EntireRow.Cells(, "B").Value
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Tim, srry about that. RejectTitleNm is the name of my ComboBox1

Comment: Thank you! Also, do I need to change the name of f to the name cell on Worksheet?

Comment: `f` is just the name of variable - it doesn't make any difference what it's called.

Comment: Ok, this still isn't working. Am I suppose to fill in a blank somewhere?

Comment: Also, my column B is named ProcessProcedures, but that doesn't see to work either?

Comment: "not working" is not a very useful description of what's happening when you try to run this.  What exactly are you seeing when you make a selection from the combo box?

Comment: Sorry, Nothing happens. I select an item in the combo box and nothing shows in the TextBox1

Comment: I apologize my TextBox1 visible setting was set to False. It works perfectly now! Thank you so much, and sorry again!