# Dynamic Checkbox select all

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox, userform

I have created a userform with a dynamic checkbox using the below code. I am struggling to figure out how to add a select all/unselect all checkbox at the bottom (or anywhere) since the list is dynamic. Any assistance will be appreciated.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

'Create Checkboxes form with director names

Dim lRow        As Long
Dim i           As Long
Dim chkBox      As MSForms.CheckBox

lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

Sheets("Directors_Database").Activate

For i = 4 To lRow

    Set chkBox = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.CheckBox.1", "CheckBox_" & i)
    chkBox.Caption = Worksheets("Directors_Database").Cells(i, 2).Value
    chkBox.Left = 5
    chkBox.Top = 5 + ((i - 2) * 20)
    chkBox.Width = 350

Next i

Set chkBox = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create the "select all" checkbox at design time, not at runtime - else it getting a little tricky to assign a Event-Routine (see [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083603/vba-using-withevents-on-userforms/1923457#1923457))

You could place the SelectAll-checkBox at the bottom by setting the `top` property (as you do already).

Then assign an Click-Event to that Checkbox:

```
Private Sub CheckBoxSelectAll_Click()

Dim c As Control

For Each c In Me.Controls
    If TypeOf c Is MSForms.CheckBox Then
        c.Value = CheckBoxSelectAll.Value
    End If
Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: Yep this is what I started to try and do after the question. I just couldn't get the syntax on like 2 of the for statement right lol. Thanks FunThomas!