# Excel VBA: How to call "on change" for a dynamically created Object?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to call a change event for any Combo Box on a userform.

**UPDATE**

So following what others have said (For Text Boxes, which I've tested and works for Textboxes), I've create a Class Module Called: 'clsCombo_Update'

```
Private WithEvents MyComboBox As MSForms.comboBox

Public Property Set Control(cb As MSForms.comboBox)
    Set MyComboBox = cb
End Property

Private Sub MyComboBox_Change()
    Debug.Print "Change"
End Sub
```

And in the UserForm I have:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim ctrl As MSForms.Control
    Dim obj As clsCombo_Update

    Set cbCollection = New Collection
        For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
            If TypeOf ctrl Is MSForms.comboBox Then
                Set obj = New clsCombo_Update
                Set obj.Control = ctrl
                cbCollection.Add obj
            End If
        Next ctrl
    Set obj = Nothing

End Sub
```

This setup worked for textboxes but doesn't when I tried to make it work for Combo Boxes

Comment: Can you simply have a "submit" button on the combo box, or something similar?

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083603/vba-using-withevents-on-userforms