# userForm - one afterChange function for all buttons

Tags: excel, vba

I have many buttons in userform. I don't want write for every buttons function "afterUpdate", because every will be similar. Is the way make it simpler than write single function for single button?

```
Sub button1_afterUpdate()

End sub


Sub button2_afterUpdate()    
    '............

    'The same code as button1 function

    '...........
End sub
```

Comment: Yes, you can probably do that, for example using a "control array".  Without any examples though, it's difficult to make any actual suggestions as to how you'd do that.

Comment: One approach is to put most of your code in a single sub and call that from each handler, passing any needed arguments.  I meant something *specific* when I suggested examples though.  I know what you mean by your question, but not exactly what you're doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way would be to create a sub for the actual code that is the seame for every button:

```
Sub RunThisForEveryButton_afterUpdate()

    'This is the same code that should run in every button

End Sub
```

And then call this sub in every event …

```
Sub button1_afterUpdate()
    RunThisForEveryButton_afterUpdate
End sub

Sub button2_afterUpdate()    
    RunThisForEveryButton_afterUpdate
End sub
```

---

Another approach is to create one event for **all** buttons using `WithEvents`.
Therefore have a look here [VBA: Using WithEvents on UserForms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1923457/3219613).

Comment: WithEvents is it what I looking for.Thanks very much.