# Dynamically Add Option Buttons to Excel UserFrm with One Event Handler

Tags: vba, events, dynamic, controls

I have a custom user form in Excel where the number of option buttons is dynamic, depending on what a user selects from a combo box.  I have written a script that will add and format those option buttons with appropriate captions, groupname, etc.  However, I would like it so that **after** those buttons are added dynamically, if a user clicks a button from a group just added, then more code will be executed.  I  am aware that one can create a custom class so that multiple userform controls are handled with one event handler, but I can't figure out how to get this to work with controls that were added dynamically to a form, after the form initialized.  I am hoping this question makes sense.  Thanks in advance for any help you can offer.

Comment: When you are adding the buttons dynamically, you should keep a track of them... (add them to a variable/array as needed). Afterwards should be easy to access them. That, or loop through all controlls `if controll = button then do this` kind of logic.

Comment: Hello, DarXyde.  Thanks for taking the time to respond.  I'm not sure I understand what you're saying, or perhaps my original question wasn't clear.  Here is some code I have:

Comment: Sorry-hit enter not realizing that would complete submission of comments. I'm not sure I understand what you're saying, or perhaps my original question wasn't clear. I do know how to loop through controls, but the problem is after I add controls dynamically, then I need an event to trigger the looping through the new controls and do something.  So for example, I can add 3 new option buttons dynamically and add them with the same groupname, but I need to make it so clicking any of those new buttons executes certain code.

Comment: Well, something like this post: [vba-using-withevents-on-userforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083603/vba-using-withevents-on-userforms/1923457#1923457).